# Got a crash related to libminikin.so not sure why this would happen

Tags: android, fonts

The entire stacktrace on the play console is

```
15 Jun 19:09 on app version 26
Asus ZenFone 2 Laser (ZE500KL) (ASUS_Z00E_2), 2048MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 1 of 3
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.bariski.cryptoniffler <<<

backtrace:

  #00  pc 0000000000008d24  /system/lib64/libminikin.so (_ZNK7android10FontFamily15getClosestMatchENS_9FontStyleE)

  #01  pc 0000000000007e1c  /system/lib64/libminikin.so (_ZN7android14FontCollection13baseFontFakedENS_9FontStyleE+28)

  #02  pc 00000000000f5d4c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so

  #03  pc 00000000022baf68  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
```

Any leads into how to debug this issue? seems like its unable to render my font. This is just happening on the Zenfone device and my app seems to be doing fine otherwise.

**Screenshot of my play console**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Information is very insufficient in your question, but from logs I can tell that `com.bariski.cryptoniffler` application is causing some issue (could be corrupted memory address or something simila) due to which `libminikin.so` NDK lib is crashing.

To debug this issue, first you need to find the pattern of this crash i.e.

Check:

1. if the steps to reproduce the issue
2. if it is 100% reproducible
3. if issue is device specific

Comment: Hi Vic, thanks for writing up, as mentioned before this is just on a Zenfone device. My app is com.bariski.cryptoniffler and I don't have any way to reproduce this and sadly play console only gives me this much info check the updated screenshot on the question. While I appreciate the sanity markers to debugging, I'm not entirely sure about getting my hands on that device.

Comment: @humblerookie ah this is from Play Store. It might be random crash then. Did you find same logs from other devices as well? Or multiple times? You can try to create emulator with Zenfone device specs and try to debug the issue there.

Comment: There aren't other devices there is just this same phone, I'll try duplicating the specs on an emulator. The crash happened a total of 6 times and has 2 variants (each 3 occurances) https://imgur.com/a/Dxoo7Ku . I'll get back on the emulator tests.

Comment: @humblerookie ok please try.